# How can I check if a user is disabled in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm writing a PHP program to list user information.

I want to check if a user in **/etc/passwd** is disabled, so I have to check if a specific user has password like *** or !** in **/etc/shadow** file.

Here is the problem, my Apache server has no access to shadow file, and I think reading shadow file is not safe in any case.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: It seems quite impossible with no root access. You wouldn't run apache as root would you ? :-) http://www.unix.com/hp-ux/43823-disabled-locked-users.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I/ Fetch the results with a root shell script run with cron.

```
for line in /etc/shadow store in /var/www/.../users.status.php
<?php die("do not open this file"); ?>
username:Active
username2:Inactive
...
```

II/ Make the php script that tests the created file with user submitted value...

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/passwd` is Apache Folder and this folder is private...
You can't  Access to it in most servers!
if user disabled on server ,he can't access to run php!

Comment: I mean read the whole user list from /etc/passwd and make judgment one by one. Not checking the current user.

Comment: `You can't Access to it in most servers!` else you can read this file by php fopen() and read lines and check it!!@!